# Unit testing a method that calls other methods Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

I was thinkig a lot on WHAT to test in a method that works like an "orchestrator" and it's only job is to calls functions. So I have this BattleInteractor class

```
class BattleInteractor {
    constructor(opts) {
        this.battleRepository = opts.battleRepository
        this.battleEntity = opts.battleEntity
        this.battleWinner = opts.battleWinner
        this.typeFactoryService = opts.typeFactory
    }
    
    async execute(pokemonOne, pokemonTwo) {

        const battleResult = this.battle(pokemonOne, pokemonTwo)
        return battleResult
    }

    battle(pokemonOne, pokemonTwo) {
        const strategy = this.typeFactoryService.getStrategy(pokemonOne, pokemonTwo)
        const pokemonsSetted = strategy.setStats(pokemonOne, pokemonTwo)
        const battleResult = this.battleEntity.battleLogic(pokemonsSetted)
        return this.battleWinner.battleWinner(battleResult)
    }

}

module.exports = BattleInteractor
```

And the test file with all methods mocked:

```
const BattleInteractor = require('../../../../src/application/useCases/battle/battleInteractor')
describe('BattleInteractor test', () => {

    const pokemonOneMock = 'mock'
    const pokemonTwoMock = 'mock'
    const battleWinnerMock = 'mock'

    class TypeMock {
        setStats() {
            return 'mockStats'
        }
    }

    const battleInteractor = new BattleInteractor({
        battleRepository: {
            savedDatabase: () => true
        },
        typeFactory: {
            getStrategy: () => {
                return new TypeMock()
            },
        },
        battleEntity: {
            battleLogic: () => {
                return "battleLogicMock"
            }
        },
        battleWinner: {
            battleWinner: () => {
                return battleWinnerMock
            }
        },
    })


    test.only('Should return properties formatted', async () => {
        const res = await battleInteractor.execute(pokemonOneMock, pokemonTwoMock)
        expect(res.message).toBe("carnivine and naganadel have tied")
    })


})
```

All works fine, so I have some questions:
What should I test in a method like this?
Is this a unit testing or a integration testing?
How necessary is it to test a class/method like this?

Comment: not an easy answer, but i for myself dont test components like this through unit tests but as you said with integration tests. As there is no real logic inside here i argue its fine to write one integration test for it that includes the modules. With that test you cover each line of this component. Imho unit tests wouldnt cover much here and would add a lot of test complexity

Comment: Do you think I can just test with "toHaveBeenCalled()" or what I did is the same?

Comment: that could be an option yes, but as i said, i wouldnt unit test this at all and just do integration tests